# css blur filter in Firefox giving shadow around the clipped area. why?

Tags: css, css-filters

I am trying to create a blurred area within an image but am having some issues with firefox adding a shadow around the clip path for some reason?

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c48fg/)

CSS:

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    background:url(http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Observer/Columnist/Columnists/2011/10/21/1319219972164/Oak-tree-in-field-007.jpg);
    height:276px;
    width:460px;
}
div:after {
    background:inherit;
    content:"";
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    position:inherit;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    filter: blur(5px); 
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); 
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px); 
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'blur\'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=\'5\' /></filter></svg>#blur");         filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='5');
    clip: rect(20px, 257px, 177px, 20px);
}
```

Please compare the link in Chrome (which looks great) and firefox (which has the shadow issue)

Thanks

Comment: Note: Firefox doesnt support css filters so Im using the filter url trick for it

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing the issue on my end in FF or Chrome.

They look identical to me ([Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBn7r.jpg)):
[image]

Comment: just updated from FF27 to FF28 and issue gone. Must be a pretty edge case bug. CHeers.